# Anaconda Environment Doesnt activate

Tags: python, environment, anaconda

So i installed an Anaconda environment according to

`conda create -n tardis --file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tardis-sn/tardis/master/pip-requirements python=2 pip`

Now I am trying to activate the environment using
`source activate tardis`

But it's giving me the following error

`pfrcks@pfrcks~ $ source activate tardis
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for activate`

Any help ??

Comment: Can you add the output of  `which conda` and `which activate` to your question?

Comment: What is the output of `type source`?