# Why is Anaconda source activate non-existent?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I successfully created two separate Python environments in Anaconda, yet seem to be unable to activate either one of them. I have tried to read up on this topic as much as possible here on Stackoverflow, yet no solution did resolve my issue. I added information asked for by comments in this question ([Anaconda Environment Doesnt activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28830238/anaconda-environment-doesnt-activate)).

When trying to activate an environment, the console output is `-bash: activate: No such file or directory`.

The output of `which conda` is `/Users/username/anaconda3/bin/conda`.
The output of `type source` is `source is a shell builtin`.
When trying `which activate`, the shell returns nothing.

In my `bin` folder, I also seem not to have an `activate` executable, but only one which is called `activate-global-python-argcomplete`.

Why do I lack the standard activate file and how I could resolve this issue best?

Answer (score 7):

I experience a similar problem. In my case, the problem is related to the use of the `tcsh`, but `activate` only supports `bash` and `zsh`.

You can check your current used shell with the command
`echo $0`.

You have to use a compatible shell in order to use the `source activate` command.

Comment: and so, how to do it on tcsh?

Answer (score 5):

I think you happened to install a buggy version of anaconda which was quickly patched.

```
conda update conda
```

should get you back up and running.

Comment: This *is* the solution that worked for me. `source activate` was working fine at first but after some package installing, I think it could've got corrupted. I was worried if I had to install the whole Anaconda again. Thanks for the simple solution.

Comment: This worked for me. `source activate` was working before I installed `conda-env`.

Answer (score 2):

Start a new terminal and try again. Alternatively, type `hash -r` and see if it helps.

Comment: Has absolutely no effect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not do this!!!, this broke my dnf**

First I tried to point source to a activate file,

```
source /usr/lib64/python3.6/venv/scripts/common/activate environment
```

That appeared to work, but no actual values got updated. I tried the answer by mattexx, but it complained conda wasn't installed, so I used.

```
conda install conda
```

*I had to have root permission since it was being installed to the root environment, but after that everything appears to work.*

**That is what broke my fedora installation**

Comment: In Fedora, activate is installed through package "conda-activate"
-> "sudo dnf install conda-activate"

Comment: Thanks, that could have helped a lot. It really seems odd that conda can be installed without activate because then it doesn't do much.

Answer (score 1):

tcsh was the problem for me. Changed to bash and all is ok.

Comment: how do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that file `/opt/pycharm/plugins/terminal/.zshrc`  (using ZSH) contained line `source $JEDITERM_SOURCE`. That variable contained correct paths as two parameters `<path-to-anaconda-activate>/activate <path-to-anaconda>`, but apparently they got interpreted as a single parameter: `<path-to-anaconda-activate>/activate <path-to-anaconda>`.

I solved that prepending `eval` to that line, making it `eval source $JEDITERM_SOURCE`. Now, the variable expands correctly.

If you're using bash then make the same change to `/opt/pycharm/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the problem might be that the virtual environment was created in `/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/` and hence the activate will be in:
`/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/NAME_OF_YOUR_VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate`

Hence to activate the environment you could run:
`source /Users/username/anaconda3/envs/NAME_OF_YOUR_VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the bash shell inside pycharm and fixed the problem by making this change:

```
[~/opt/pycharm-community/plugins/terminal]$ diff jediterm-bash.in.old jediterm-bash.in
65c65
<   source "$JEDITERM_SOURCE"
---
>   eval source "$JEDITERM_SOURCE"
```

Essentially making the same change recommended above by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564931/netchkin, but to `~/opt/pycharm-community/plugins/terminal/jediterm-bash.in`.

This fixed my existing projects.  But any new projects don't seem to try and activate the conda environment at all.  It seems as if new projects created in Pycharm 2017.1.2 don't set the `JEDITERM_SOURCE` variable when starting a session in the terminal plugin.

There is an open issue on this at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23417

Looks like there was a big change to the conda activate script in version 4.4.0.  See https://conda.io/docs/release-notes.html. If I downgrade conda to 4.3.34 then I can get conda virtual environments to work in the pycharm terminal again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I did:

```
which conda
```

Output:

```
conda () {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
        (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
            __conda_reactivate ;;
        (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

So, to activate my environment I did:

```
source activate env
```