# Anaconda commands on visual code remote terminal stopped working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

When I'm working not in visual code (linux terminal or powershell for example) everything is working fine. I succeed to run conda commands. For example, I succeed to ran `conda version` and other commands, and I manage to run `source activate my_env` or `conda activate my_env` to enter conda environment.

When I worked with remote ssh on visual studio (using intel Devcloud if it says something) everything was also fine, and I managed to everything I done above in the terminal that is provided in by visual studio.

Today, I had some problem with my environments, so I deleted some and created new ones. As a result, thing stopped working only in visual code terminal. when I try to perform conda command I get `conda: command not found`, and when I try `source activate my_env` I get `bash: activate: No such file or directory`.

I saw that in general it got something with the PATH (I don't really understand how but I saw it), but here everything works fine when not using visual code. In addition, since I'm working on cloud, people suggestion to add something like this `export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` is not possible to me as I don't have this kind of location. Instead my environments are located on  `/home/user_name/.conda/envs`.

(side problem that I got is that when I tried to delete one of my environment, I saw that its directory in `/home/user_name/.conda/envs` is still there, and when I tried to delete it with rm -rf I get error `rm: cannot remove 'kerasenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/~umpy/core': Permission denied`).

I broke my head to understand what is the problem.

**Edit:** Some information per *Jill Cheng* question. I used the following command to delete the old environment:

```
conda env remove --name ENVIRONMENT
```

I also uploaded an image of the working space and the terminal with some of the commands that I tried. (by the way  the environment called kerasenv is the directory that I can't remove)
[image]

Comment: How did you delete the previous environment? What is the new environment you created? And it will be better resolved if you could provide us with relevant screenshots.

Comment: Thank you for adding this information. And I noticed that the current environment is not shown here in the lower left corner of VSCode. Have you tried to choose the environment for it? (You could try to use the shortcut key "Ctrl+Shift+p" to open the panel, enter "Python:select Interpreter", and select the environment you need.)

Comment: @JillCheng I have updated the photo so that it contain the python interpreter. This is something that works, and even I succeed to run codes on the environment. The problem is that I can't use the terminal on the VScode, and therefore I very limited. for example, visual studio can't update automatically things in my environment, and I even can't do it myself using the VScode terminal.

Comment: If this conda environment is available in the cmd window outside of VSCode, it can also be used in the terminal of VSCode. So you could try to use the shortcut key **Ctrl+Shift+`** to open a new VSCode terminal, it will automatically enter the currently selected environment, which can prevent the terminal from being in the previous environment.

Comment: @JillCheng trying to do this summarize the problem. I get this error: 
bash: activate: No such file or directory.

Comment: There is a situation where there is a issue with conda, so you could try the method provided in this link to update conda with "conda update conda": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488081/why-is-anaconda-source-activate-non-existent/40242411